# Creating new column taking single value from column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. The first one is `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 0], 'B': [2, 4]})` i.e

```
    A   B
0   5   2
1   0   4
```

another one is `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': [1, 1], 'D': [3, 3]})` i.e

```
    C   D
0   1   3
1   1   3
```

I want want to grab only 4 from df1 and make new column in df2. I have tried this `df2['E']=df1['B'][df1['B']==4]` and got

```
    C   D    E
0   1   3   NaN
1   1   3   4.0
```

I want both rows of df2 to be 4. How can I achieve this? Any help would be immense help.

Comment: If you already know you want it to be 4, just do `df2['E']=4`  otherwise there must be some other logic you aren't telling us about.  Are you trying to get the `max` of `B` or the last value?  Must be something.

Comment: Thank you @Chris but I have bigger data than this. This just for readability and clear questioning. There is any other other method you can suggest other than this ?

Comment: @Chris Not I don't want `max` of `B` neither last value. I just want code which can do this for any value.

Comment: so are you just checking to see if the value is there and if so, fill a new column with that value?  What if that value is not there, do you want a null value?

Comment: @Chris yes. Yes if the values is not there than its fine if i get NaN

Answer (score 0):

if the value '4' appears as the last value in your column( like your example), you could do:

```
df2['E'].fillna(method= 'backfill')
```

for other methods, have a look here:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not actually clear what you wanna accomplish here, but I assume you would like to check if there is any "4" in df1 (column B) and then filling all rows in df2 (column E) with "4". Then you could do:

```
import numpy as np

df2['E'] = np.where(df1['B'].isin([4]).any(), 4, np.nan)
```

Output:

```
    C   D     E
0   1   3   4.0
1   1   3   4.0
```

Comment: I want to check lets say `4` as in example first,  if the value is there I want to  fill a new column with that value only.

Comment: So if you use the solution I provided, you will get expected results.

Comment: Is there any other way in pandas itself without numpy. What if I don't wat float value but just `4` ? Can please suggest me ?

Comment: Numpy solution is the most reasonable to me and it's the only one I can suggest here. If you wanna see values as integers, add .astype(int) at the end.